# How to search through an array of integers and strings and return the name and score of the highest competitor - python 3.10

Tags: python

this will probably be comically simple but I can't figure out the answer basically have to search through a 2d array something that I can't remember

what I have figured out doesn't help so was looking for some help

the code I have is as follows:

```
competitors = [["John", 11], ["Jenny", 13], ["Matthew", 3], ["Bev", 22], ["Claire", 12]]
```

Comment: Surely you can write a loop to go through these elements one by one.   Show us that loop.  You can actually do this with one call to the `max` function.

Comment: Where on Earth did you find Python 3.1?

Comment: `max(competitors, key = lambda x:x[1])`

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні -- I suspect they dropped the zero from 3.10, assuming it was not significant.

Comment: @TimRoberts that's hilarious, but you're probably right...

Comment: @TimRoberts true

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If the question is answered you should either mark the answer that solved your problem, or in case none fits, post the solution yourself and mark that one accepted. Or you delete the question if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max()` function can take an optional `key` argument that lets you specify what python should be looking specifically to determine the maximum value, especially helpful when you have complex objects and you need to determine whether the max is the alphabetical sort of the name as a string (for example), or the top value of the integer. In our case, we want the 1st index value from each item (the integer) to determine maximum values.

```py
competitors = [
    ["John", 11],
    ["Jenny", 13],
    ["Matthew", 3],
    ["Bev", 22],
    ["Claire", 12],
]

top_competitor = max(competitors, key=lambda x: x[1])

print(top_competitor)  # ['Bev', 22]
```

Comment: thanks what does the max() do probably should say I'm only a beginner

Comment: Updated my answer explaining.